# Sendgrid - json could not be unmarshalled

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

anyone used the **v3/marketing/singlesends** endpoint from Sendgrid? This request doesn't work with POST or PUT. And the error it's like a server error
Any ideas?

```
Client error: `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
{"errors":[{"field":"","message":"json could not be unmarshalled"}]}
```

Comment: Check you input params. Maybe you send integer or boolean like a string

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you provide wrong input.also the api was changed on may6th

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/single-sends-2020-update/